# Import a video without changing its size/aspect ratio

Tags: rendering, import

I have a 888x1920 portrait video, which i want to import into a 1920x1080 landscape area. But as soon as i do that, the video gets stretched so it fits the 1920x1080 size. I have also tried ticking "Offset" in the right side panel, then adding a transform effect strip, scaling it down, but then the top half of the video gets cut off.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "import", do you mean add it as an image strip in the video sequencer?  In that case, you select *Use Original Size* as the *Fit Method* when you Add the movie or image sequence.

Or do you mean you want to add it in the 3D viewport as a texture you use on the larger object?  In that case, You want to add a mapping node, use UV coordinates, and adjust both the location and scale of X and Y appropriately.

Here is an example material that I used to place a 1080p movie on a 1x1 aspect ratio plane:

[image: placing a 1080p movie on a 1 x 1 aspect ratio plane]

Comment: I seem to be missing [this](https://i.gyazo.com/e9721d140397dd1beb596a103e64fe6f.png) option? (importing to the video editor)

Comment: what version of blender are you using?  The option is present in 2.93

Comment: im using version 2.90.1

Comment: There have been a lot of changes to VSE during 2.9x.  If you can update to 2.93.3 you probably should.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works now